# Waking up Nodes

Tags: kaleido

We've created an environment on Kaleido and an API to communicate with the Private Network.

If there isn't any activity for a certain duration. The nodes on Kaleido go to sleep.

Our API returns an error obviously attempting to connect with the Node but returns error unresponsive.

We have to manually login into Kaleido to wake up the Nodes.

My question is:

- Is there a way to remotely wake up the nodes?
- Is this simply a feature in the free tier?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If your environment has been paused, you can the the PATCH API for the environment to resume all of the nodes within.

```
curl -X PATCH -d '{"state":"live"}' -H "$HDR_AUTH" -H "$HDR_CT" "$APIURL/consortia/{consortia_id}/environments/{environment_id}"
```

This will put your environment into a `resume_pending` state while it wakes the nodes, at which point the state will automatically be updated to `live`.

Currently, all environments will automatically pause after a set period of inactivity. If your use case needs a longer time before pausing, you can submit feedback via the Kaleido UI requesting an increase.

Comment: Hi Galen,

Thanks for the help on waking up the nodes.

I have one more question in regards to using the PATCH request to send the nodes to sleep? (We want to test behaviour if the nodes are asleep)

Comment: You can PATCH the state to `paused` to manually put an environment to sleep.